# Does the owner of an encrypted directory need to be logged for it to be accessible by the system?

Tags: disk-encryption

Does the owner of an encrypted directory need to be logged for it to be accessible by the system?

If the user's directory is encrypted, ie other directories besides the `home` directory, does it mean that no process on the system, including those running as root will be able to access it?

Does the user have to be logged in physically on the  computer for the files to be available? For instance, I assume that the user cannot log in via SSH using key authentication if the `authorized_keys` file which would be in the `~/.ssh` directory, but have to login at the terminal  for via a remote `spice` connection for access to the directory to be enabled,   before logging in via SSH if that is needed.

If the user has a database or web application stored in the encrypted directory I  would expect it not to be able to start until physical login.

Is that right because that is what I need. If there any services running in the encrypted directory, would the system know to shut them down if the user logged out?

Comment: To access the encrypted dir, you need the key, not the user. If you want to do ssh etc, then don't encrypt the whole home directory.

Comment: Are you meaning logged (a record being made of activity) or logged-in (to be authenticated and using the system)?

Comment: @richard I mean `logged-in`. For instance if I have to log in at the  terminal  before I can log in via `ssh`, if I log out of the   terminal while still logged in via `ssh` I  expect the file system to be available until I log out of the last `ssh` sesion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use a system that encrypts your user(s) home directory(s) individually.  The only implementation that makes sense is to mount the encrypted directory at login time.  For example, you can find this system offered in the Ubuntu installer using `ecryptfs`.  (ecryptfs is also built in as part of Chrome OS).  This is a different approach from "Full Disk Encryption", where the whole filesystem is unlocked with a password at the start of the boot process.  All your desires follow naturally from `ecryptfs` or any equivalent system... except for the last one

> If there any services running in the encrypted directory, would the system know to shut them down if the user logged out?

"Good question" :).  Unfortunately unmounting appears to be more error-prone.  (I've also seen bugs in stopping processes/services, which is indeed a pre-condition for unmounting.  I'm not clear whether ecryptfs has any extra support to kill processes).

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ecryptfs%20logout%20unmount%20OR%20umount

Since this question left this for the last sentence, & is also impossibly unspecific, you might want to ask a separate question.  E.g. "does this work on X version Y.  Please show how you know it works, then I will be able to verify it on my own system."

It would also be nice if you could outline reasons you're interested in logout at all.  It suggests a multi-user system.  This is not very common, so if you can be more specific that would probably be useful.

Comment: I haven't chosen one yet as I haven't looked them up yet. I have heard of systems like `dmcrypt`,  `LUKS`, `encryptfs`, `EndFS` and now `ecryptfs`, but where it comes to a user owned directory I assume some commonality among the suitable  ones.

Comment: @vfclists that's fair up to a point.  Unfortunately the last point is a quality of implementation question.

Comment: Say I have account for administering an number of remote systems ssh key authentication. I want to be able to log into the account with the encrypted file system, use the keys to adminster the remote systems and logout when I  am done. I basically want to reduce the time when a key compromise may be possible, and also protect against theft of the PC.

Comment: To be honest the ability to turn of services that depend on the encrypted files being available is simply ice on the cake. It will probably depend on a logout script which can verify that it is the last one running to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. In a normal setup where a user's home directory is encrypted (with ecryptfs), as opposed to when the whole partition is encrypted (with dmcrypt), then the decrypted files are only visible while the user is logged in. However, there is no strong link between files-are-visible and user-is-logged-in: the way it works is that the encrypted filesystem is mounted (making the files visible) as one of the steps of logging the user in, and the encrypted filesystem is unmounted (making the files no longer visible) as one of the steps of logging the user out.

The user does not have to be logged in physically. It doesn't matter how the user logs in. It may be difficult for the user to log in over SSH, because by default the user's public key would only be recorded inside the encrypted filesystem, so it wouldn't be visible when the user tries to log in and the encrypted filesystem isn't mounted. However the user could authenticate with a different method such as a password (typing the password is necessary to decrypt the files anyway), or could create a `.ssh/authorized_keys` in the non-encrypted home directory (it's [cumbersome](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/362427/comments/12) but doable).

If you need to control when the unmounting is done, you'll need to remove `~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount` and instead call `ecryptfs-umount-private` directly at the desired time.